# When does one capitalize the word "city"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the UK, when does one capitalize the word "city"?  As in My City does not approve of trash receptacles.

Comment: Only if you are referring to a local government body such as the City Council, or some other proper name.

Comment: In Britain, we don't really have "trash receptacles"; we have rubbish bins.

Comment: What city would disapprove of trash receptacles? This seems beyond bizarre to me…

Comment: One example would be a city in which terrorists have left bombs in them. Many places in Britain removed them following IRA bomb attacks in the 1980s.

Answer (score 1):

There is precisely one time when you capitalize the word 'city' - when it is actually part of a proper name, for example the name of the city itself or some entity related to the city.

So you can write "Manchester City" (either the municipality or the football team), because that is the name. But generally you should use lowercase when referring to "my city", "the city", "a city" etc.

So the following are correct:

- I work for Manchester City
- I play for Manchester City
- The motion was discussed by Manchester City Council
- His formal title is 'City Treasurer'.
- Manchester is a city in England
- The nearest city is called Manchester
- I live in a city called Manchester
- Manchester is not the city I mean
- He is the treasurer for the city.

Comment: You would also capitalize when it's appropriate to capitalize the name of an organization, such as the City Council.  This varies greatly by context, though.